# Transformations on sets of measure zero in probability space

Tags: stochastic-processes, measure-theory, ergodic

Given a probability space $(X, \Sigma,\mu, T)$, where $\mu$ is a probability measure, $\Sigma$ is a sigma algebra on $X$, and $T$ is a transformation, then a 'measure preserving transformation' is one which implies,

$\mu(T^{-1}(A)) = \mu(A)$

Whereby $A \subseteq \Sigma$. Now, allowing $A$ to be a set of measure zero, let us suggest,

$T(A)=B$

Whereby $\mu(B)> 0$, implying that,

$\mu(T^{-1}(B)) \neq \mu(B)$

That is, given,

$\mu(T^{-1}(B)) = \mu(A)=0$

An example of this could be the situation in which a transformation on a variable in $X$ that was formerly presumed to be gaussian reveals that it is actually a member of a distribution of greater kurtosis.

Assuming the above notation and explanation is accurate, would this imply that:

1) that the transformation *is not* a 'measure preserving transformation'

2) that this transformation *is not* 'weakly mixing'

3) that this transformation *is not* 'ergodic'

Comment: Normally one would consider a "transformation" to be a function $T:X\to X$, in which case $T(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ is the only possibility for $B$, whence $\mu(B)=0$.  Since you have supposed something that contradicts this conclusion, could you please explain what you mean by a transformation?

Comment: Hi Whuber, thanks for your reply. I think I have used the notion of a 'null set' in the wrong way - what I was trying to express was that the set in question, say $A$, has a measure of zero prior to the transformation but a measure greater than zero after. Allow me to edit the post to express this. Thanks again.

Comment: It sounds impossible to define such a measure and such a transform. If $A$ is of measure $0$, so is $T(A)$. And the remark about the kurtosis sounds disconnected from the question.